# In Common Lisp, how to use lexical scope and funcall to make another function be passed as an argument?

Tags: common-lisp, anonymous-function, lexical-scope, funcall

I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime. Hence, I can do:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defvar example #'(lambda (x) (* x 20)))
EXAMPLE

CL-USER> (funcall example 10)
200
```

Ok. It works as expected. Using the library Dexador, I can also so:

```lisp
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :dexador)
To load "dexador":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    dexador
; Loading "dexador"
.......
(:DEXADOR)

CL-USER> (dex:get "http://www.paulgraham.com")
"big HTML ommited"
200
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 11 {10029F1443}>
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTP http://www.paulgraham.com>
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "socket 10.0.0.193:44936, peer: 74.6.52.135:80" {1002681F73}>
```

Now, I am trying to make the argument to be passed be a function! More specifically, the `dex:get` function. I tried different approaches, but none of them worked out:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defvar example-failing #'(lambda (x) (x "http://www.paulgraham.com")))
; in: DEFVAR EXAMPLE-FAILING
;     (LAMBDA (X) (X "http://www.paulgraham.com"))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable X is defined but never used.
; in: DEFVAR EXAMPLE-FAILING
;     (X "http://www.paulgraham.com")
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::X
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     X
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
EXAMPLE-FAILING
CL-USER> (funcall example-failing dex:get)
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE GET {1002C57103}>.
CL-USER> (funcall example-failing 'dex:get)
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION X {1002DEA263}>.
CL-USER> (funcall example-failing #'dex:get)
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION X {1002F906C3}>.
CL-USER> (funcall example-failing (function dex:get))
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION X {1003147F83}>.
```

I managed to do it with:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defvar hacky-eval #'(lambda (x) (eval x)))
HACKY-EVAL
CL-USER> (funcall hacky-eval (dex:get "http://www.paulgraham.com"))
"big html omitted"
```

But, this feels as bad practice. Is there **another** way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
(defvar example-failing
  #'(lambda (x)
     (x "http://www.paulgraham.com")))
```

This makes no sense in Common Lisp. `x` is a variable. You can't use a variable as a function as in `(x arg)`. In Common Lisp there are different namespaces for functions and variables. For example `LET` introduces a local variable and `FLET` introduces a local function.

The ways to call a function bound to a variable are:

```
(funcall x arg)

(apply x (list arg))
```

Thus correct examples would be:

```
(defvar example-failing
  #'(lambda (x)
     (apply x (list "http://www.paulgraham.com"))))
```

or

```
(defvar example-failing
  #'(lambda (x)
     (funcall x "http://www.paulgraham.com")))
```

**Your solution is no solution**

This is your example:

```
CL-USER> (defvar hacky-eval #'(lambda (x) (eval x)))
HACKY-EVAL
CL-USER> (funcall hacky-eval (dex:get "http://www.paulgraham.com"))
"big html omitted"
```

This does not work as you think.

```
(funcall hacky-eval (dex:get "http://www.paulgraham.com"))
```

is just the same as

```
(funcall hacky-eval "big html omitted")
```

and then

```
(eval "big html omitted")
```

and then

```
"big html omitted"
```

All your call to `eval` does is to evaluate a string to itself.

You really need to understand basic evaluation rules in Lisp:

```
(defun foo (arg)
  (eval arg))

(foo (+ 3 4))
```

is simply the same as:

```
(defun foo (arg)
  arg)

(foo (+ 3 4))
```

which is the same as

```
(identity (+ 3 4))
```

Note: **if you pass just self evaluating data to EVAL, then all it does is to return the data**

A function call `(foo (+ 1 2))` works like this:

1. Lisp sees that FOO is a function
2. Lisp evaluates the arguments. (+ 1 2) -> 3
3. Lisp calls the function FOO with the evaluated argument: (funcall #'foo 3)
4. Lisp computes the function FOO: (EVAL 3) -> 3
5. Lisp returns the value(s) from FOO -> 3

Answer (score 4):

I am confused by your question although not as confused as you seem to be.  You already seem to know that, to call a function which is the value of a variable, you need either

- `funcall` if you have all the arguments as individual things;
- `apply` if you have only a list of arguments;

and that to get the function value of something you need `(function thing)` or equivalently `#'thing`[1].

But then you forget that in your function, and pay no attention to the copious warnings from SBCL.

So

```
(defvar *example* (lambda (f) (funcall f "http://www.paulgraham.com")))
...
(funcall *example* #'dex:get)
```

Note that none of this (and nothing in your question) relies on lexical scope: this would all have worked in any historical Lisp.

---

[1]: you don't need `#'` for `(lambda ...)` only because `lambda` is a macro which expands into `(function (lambda ...))`.  Very old code sometimes uses the explicit `#'(lambda ...)` form since this macro did not always exist in CL.

Comment: Is there two parentheses missing in your post? Maybe `(defvar *example* (lambda (f) (funcall f "http://www.paulgraham.com")))` ?

Comment: @PedroDelfino yes there were, thank you.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using a proper `defun`:

```lisp
(defun request (url)
  (dex:get url))

CL-USER> (request "http://…")
```

Now you want to use something else than `dex:get`? Well… write another function, because their argument handling, headers, return values… might be different.

```lisp
(defun request-drakma (url)
   (drakma:… url))
```

Maybe in later code you want to reference to either function?

```lisp
(defun do-request (url &optional (get-fn #'request))
  (funcall get-fn url))
```

---

```
(defvar example #'(lambda (x) (* x 20)))
```

Here you are giving a name to an anonymous function… just use `defun`^^